# AttributeError: 'UserVote' object has no attribute 'model' in Django

Tags: django

Trying to add this voter class to a custom user model. I don't think I needed to create a custom model the way I did, but I'm already into it and I'd prefer not to start from scratch. Basically, I'm trying to create a matching system where two users can select yes or no to each other and then be matched. Anyhow, the migrations worked. But, when I go to add it to admin.py, I get

**Error**

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/checks.py", line 56, in check_admin_app
    errors.extend(site.check(app_configs))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 81, in check
    if modeladmin.model._meta.app_config in app_configs:
AttributeError: 'UserVote' object has no attribute 'model'
```

**Models.py **

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser,BaseUserManager, User
from dating_project import settings



class ProfileManager(BaseUserManager):



    def create_user(self, username, email,description,photo, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("You must creat an email")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("You must create a username!")
        if not description:
            raise ValueError("You must write a description")
        if not photo:
            raise ValueError("You must upload a photo")

        user = self.model(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                username = username, 
                description= description,
                photo= photo,

            )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user 


    def create_superuser(self, username, email,description,photo, password):
        user = self.create_user(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                password=password,
                username=username,
                description=description,
                photo=photo,

            )

        user.is_admin=True
        user.is_staff=True
        user.is_superuser=True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user




class Profile(AbstractBaseUser):

    email                       = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email")
    username                    = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined                 = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login                  = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active                   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #what I added
    description                 = models.TextField()
    photo                       = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_photo',blank=False, height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100)
    #owner                      = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE) (not working, for tracking owner of profile)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['description','photo','email']


    objects = ProfileManager()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin


    def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
        return True



class UserVote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    voter = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='given_vote')
    vote = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'voter'))
```

**settings.py**

```
#For Custom Model 
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'dating_app.Profile'
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from dating_app.models import Profile,UserVote

admin.site.register(Profile,UserVote)
```

Comment: Can you share the traceback?

Comment: @lainshelvington ok, just did it

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Figured it out.

To register multiple models at once you need to pass them as iterable:

ie:

**admin.site.register([Profile,UserVote])**

rather than

**admin.site.register(Profile,UserVote)**